# Number of ways to invite 7 friends for dinner in triplets.

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can you invite 7 friends to dinner in triplets throughout a period of 7 days so that no 3 friends are invited 2 times?

It means that for each day you invite 3 of your friends. What I thought about was to allocate one friend to all the days and another the same way so that I have to allocate friends to as little as possible places, in order to have a maximum of 2 friends invited more than 1 time. But after I did I saw that it is impossible to do so as I have invited 2 friends the maximum number of times I can and I have to allocate the 5 remaining friends in the 7 remaining places that have to be filled. Therefore at least one of the remaining has to repeated more than once. This leads me to the conclusion that this is impossible and that the question means that no 3 friends have to be repeated exactly 2 times instead of 2 times or more.

If this is the case could anyone provide me with a solution. The answer is 151 200. Any help would be greatly appreciated as this my homework for tomorrow.

Comment: Your question is hard to read; you should divide paragraphs.

Comment: I did what you suggested

Comment: Does the question mean that no particular trio of friends is invited twice?

Comment: More like there can be at most 2 friends invited twice.

Comment: Your interpretation of the question makes it impossible. I had the same interpretation as @N.F.Taussig, where you are not allowed to repeat any triplet, i.e. all the invited triplets are different. Unfortunately, with this interpretation I get the answer $6 724 520$, which is much larger than the answer you have. If I ensure that every friend gets included at least once, I get $6 184 400$, still too big. Maybe the question means that amongst your friends, at most two are invited *exactly* twice. Regardless, the question is not clear.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what would be the solution if the interpretation was exactly twice